# How to run parcel && nodemon squentially in one terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, parceljs

I am trying to let parcel compile my ts file and output it to the dist folder and after that run the file with nodemon. But only my watcher is showing up in my terminal. How can I see my server in the terminal or in a second terminal without too much of a hassle? I need to run them sequentially.

```
"dev": "npm run build && npm run serve",
"build": "parcel ./src/bot.ts --target node --no-source-maps",
"serve": "npx nodemon ./dist/bot.js localhost 8080"
```

Outputs this int the terminal

```
$ npm run dev

> bot@1.0.0 dev D:\test/bot
> parcel ./src/bot.ts --target node --no-source-maps && npx nodemon ./dist/bot.js localhost 8080

✨  Built in 18ms.
```

While my bot file contains a log

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Client } from 'discord.js';

console.log('hello world');
```

So it should show

```
[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./dist/bot.js localhost 8080`
hello world
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

**Edit**: I tried using concurently like this

```
"dev": "concurrently \"npm:build\" \"npm:serve\"",
"build": "parcel ./src/bot.ts --target node --no-source-maps",
"serve": "npx nodemon ./dist/bot.js localhost 8080"
```

But it doesn't run sequentially

While this

```
   "dev": "npm run build && npm run serve",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/bot.ts --target node --no-source-maps",
    "serve": "npx nodemon ./dist/bot.js localhost 8080"
```

runs it sequentially but it doesn't watch ts file for changes since it is a build command. The && checks the left side if it returns without error and the problem is a watcher never returns while a build does return but it only runs once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to drop parcel install

```
npm install ts-node
```

and use

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/bot.ts"
},
```

which works like a charm